# Django: View and View-Test working against each other

Tags: python, django, testing, automated-tests

right now I'm trying to test one of my really simple views - which is working totally fine - and receiving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\someone\Documents\django_tests\app\tests\test_views.py", line 42, in test_person_post
ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000262BBE2CF10>>": "Person.created_from" must be a "CustomUser" instance.
```

I've changed the default *auth.user.model* with *AbstractUser* and changed it into mail/password-, instead of username/password-combination.

**models.py:**

```
class Person(models.Model):

    GENDERS = (
        ('-', '-'),
        ('Diverse', 'Diverse'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Male', 'Male'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, choices=GENDERS, default=GENDERS[0][1])
    born = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    adult = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_from = models.ForeignKey(USER, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['last_name', 'first_name'], name="unique person constraint"),
        ]
        verbose_name = "Person"
        verbose_name_plural = "Persons"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"api/persons/{self.id}/"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

**forms.py:**

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = [
            'id',
            'adult',
            'created_from',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
```

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    form = PersonForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            person = form.save(commit=False)
            person.created_from = request.user
            person.save()
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

**test_views.py:**

```
USER = get_user_model()

class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = USER.objects.create_user('test@email.com', 'testpassword')
        self.client = Client()
        self.persons_get_post = reverse('index')

def test_person_post(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.persons_get_post, {
        'first_name': 'Jane',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'gender': 'Female',
        'born': datetime.date(1900, 1, 1),
        'adult': True,
        'created_from': self.user,
        'created_date': timezone.now(),
        'updated_date': timezone.now()
    })
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
    self.assertEquals(self.person_obj.expenses.first().first_name, 'Jane')
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Django | Tests</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

Why does the test-file throws this error or what am I doing wrong, when the view itself works perfectly fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the solution: the test-view was sending the data as json by default, so all I had to change/add, was the information for the header inside my **test_views.py**:

```
def test_person_post(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.persons_get_post, {
        'first_name': 'Jane',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'gender': 'Female',
        'born': datetime.date(1900, 1, 1),
        'adult': True,
        'created_from': self.user,
        'created_date': timezone.now(),
        'updated_date': timezone.now()
    }, content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```